# Select 2 columns that match, but one is prefixed with '-'..?

Tags: sqlite

I'm currently looking at a SQLite database as a bit of a side project.

I know 2 tables match off a set ID however in one table it stores it as '123456' and in the other as '-123456'.

Is there a way to run a query against this to join these tables on this value but NOT change the original database(so no updates or replaces)..?

I've had a bit of a google and most solutions to this appear to be to update  the table.

sorry if this has been asked I had a quick search too with no success.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `table2` is the one with the negative ids, something like

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.id = abs(t2.id)
```

should work.